# Display error on Question status?

Tags: bug

Recently when i click into a question which shows already having an accepted answer, i often see actually there is not.

**like :**

[image]

**but :**

[image]

Is it only a issue for me or it is a common issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The green color means that there are answers posted in the question. The "x answer" text in the green box turns yellow if there is an accepted answer